# How TopShelf can capture arguments like 'install' or 'start' which is ignored by my Main method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, topshelf

I was checking the TopShelf as a beginner.

I see that when you compile your console app you can install your service as:

```
MySampleWindowsService.exe install
```

and start:

```
MySampleWindowsService.exe start
```

What I do not understand is my console app does not do anything with those parameters.

**Question**:So how the TopShelf captures those 'install' or 'start' arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably uses [`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) or [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx).

The command line of a process is stored in a special area of memory set aside when the process is created, which is how it's available at any time during the process's execution. It can be retrieved by the native [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which is the "official" way of getting command-line arguments in a Windows process, and is wrapped by the .NET `Environment` members.

Passing the command line as parameters to the "main" function in many languages is a convenience provided by the language. The compiler generates startup code that calls `GetCommandLine` and passes the result as a parameter to `main` (or equivalent). Similarly, the return value (if any) from `main` is usually set as the process's exit code by compiler-generated process tear-down logic.